# How to substitute the result from FindRoot into another equation?

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

I have an equation $cos(k) = cos(q) + \frac{U_{0}}{q}sin(q),$ where the value of U runs from -2 to 2, and the value of k runs from $-\pi$ to $\pi.$ Now, I need to use the values of q to compute for $E = \frac{q^{2}}{2}.$ Lastly, I need to plot E vs. k. But I am having a problem in substituting the value of q into E. My code looks like this:

```
EmptyList = List[];
 Do[Monitor[
   roots = 
    FindRoot[
     Cos[k] == Cos[q] + (1/q)*Sin[q], {q, \[Pi]}];
   E[roots_] := roots^2/2;
   AppendTo[EmptyList, {k, E}]
   , {k, E}]
 , {k, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
ListPlot[EmptyList]
```

EDITED1: I'll just $U_{0}=-1.$

EDITED2: My new code looks like this:

```
EmptyList = List[];
Do[Monitor[
  var = FindRoot[Cos[k] == Cos[q] + (1/q)*Sin[q], {q, \[Pi]}];
  energy = var^2/2;
  AppendTo[EmptyList, {k, energy}];
  , {k, energy}]
, {k, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

EmptyList has this value:

```
{{-\[Pi], {1/2 (q -> 3.14159)^2}}, {1 - \[Pi], {1/
2 (q -> 2.47905)^2}}, {2 - \[Pi], {1/
2 (q -> -1.72719)^2}}, {3 - \[Pi], {1/
2 (q -> 1.31405)^2}}, {4 - \[Pi], {1/
2 (q -> -1.55868)^2}}, {5 - \[Pi], {1/
2 (q -> 2.25107)^2}}, {6 - \[Pi], {1/2 (q -> 3.03703)^2}}}
```

Comment: You can start by not using `E` as function name, since `E` is special function in Mathematica.  Why not run each line of code on its own first and see what it does? Even your `FindRoot` gives error.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose you to use `Table` instead of `Do`. This way, for example:

```
lst1 = Table[{k, FindRoot[Cos[k] == Cos[q] + (1/q)*Sin[q], {q, \[Pi]}][[1,2]]}, {k, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 0.1}];
```

This yields a rather strange result `q=q(k)` with discontinuities:

```
ListPlot[lst1, AxesLabel -> {Style["k", 16, Italic], Style["q", 16, Italic]}]
```

[image]

Be aware of the fact that if you take a different initial guess for the FindRoot, say, k, then the result will be quite different.

```
lst2 = Table[{k, FindRoot[Cos[k] == Cos[q] + (1/q)*Sin[q], {q, k}][[1, 
      2]]}, {k, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 0.1}];

ListPlot[lst2, AxesLabel -> {Style["k", 16, Italic], Style["q", 16, Italic]}]
```

[image]

Which one of these two (and probably some others) is right is up to you.

Have fun!

Comment: Alexei Boulbitch, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved it. I just added q /. in var (line3):

```
EmptyList = List[];
Do[Monitor[
  var = q /. FindRoot[Cos[k] == Cos[q] + (1/q)*Sin[q], {q, \[Pi]}];
  energy = var^2/2;
  AppendTo[EmptyList, {k, energy}];
  , {k, energy}]
 , {k, -\[Pi], \[Pi], 0.01}]
```